# removing # OR the first line of data allows me to enter it in the db?

Tags: mysql, input, hashtag

So, I set up a new database and a table, nothing fancy, just a fast sloppy mysql db that's good enough for now:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `cards` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `setNumber` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `setYear` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `setName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `setCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `owned` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `goal` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `rarity` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `atribute` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `race` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `special` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `atk` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `def` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `cards`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `cards`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Here's the interesting part:

I try to populate the table with some data:

```
INSERT INTO `cards` (`ID`, `Name`, `setNumber`, `setYear`, `setName`, `setCode`, `owned`, `goal`, `rarity`, `atribute`, `level`, `race`, `special`, `type`, `atk`, `def`, `text`, `link`) VALUES 
(NULL, 'Skull Servant','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','DARK','1','Zombie','','Normal','300','200','A skeletal ghost that isn\'t strong but can mean trouble in large numbers.','foff?ope=2&cid=4030'),
(NULL, 'Dark Magician','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','Ultra Rare','DARK','7','Spellcaster','','Normal','2500','2100','The ultimate wizard in terms of attack and defense.','foff?ope=2&cid=4041'),
(NULL, 'Gaia The Fierce Knight','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','Ultra Rare','EARTH','7','Warrior','','Normal','2300','2100','A knight whose horse travels faster than the wind. His battle-charge is a force to be reckoned with.','foff?ope=2&cid=4044'),
(NULL, 'Celtic Guardian','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','Super Rare','EARTH','4','Warrior','','Normal','1400','1200','An elf who learned to wield a sword, he baffles enemies with lightning-swift attacks.','foff?ope=2&cid=4047'),
(NULL, 'Basic Insect','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','EARTH','2','Insect','','Normal','500','700','Usually found traveling in swarms, this creature\'s ideal environment is the forest.','foff?ope=2&cid=4056'),
(NULL, 'Mammoth Graveyard','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','EARTH','3','Dinosaur','','Normal','1200','800','A mammoth that protects the graves of its pack and is absolutely merciless when facing grave-robbers.','foff?ope=2&cid=4065'),
(NULL, 'Silver Fang','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','EARTH','3','Beast','','Normal','1200','800','A snow wolf that\'s beautiful to the eye, but absolutely vicious in battle.','foff?ope=2&cid=4071'),
(NULL, 'Dark Gray','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','EARTH','3','Beast','','Normal','800','900','Entirely gray, this beast has rarely been seen by mortal eyes.','foff?ope=2&cid=4119'),
(NULL, 'Trial of Nightmare','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','DARK','4','Fiend','','Normal','1300','900','This fiend passes judgment on enemies that are locked in coffins.','foff?ope=2&cid=4125'),
(NULL, 'Nemuriko','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','DARK','3','Spellcaster','','Normal','800','700','A child-like creature that controls a sleep fiend to beckon enemies into eternal slumber.','foff?ope=2&cid=4135'),
(NULL, 'The 13th Grave','1','03/08/2002','LEGEND OF BLUE EYES WHITE DRAGON','','0','3','','DARK','3','Zombie','','Normal','1200','900','A zombie that suddenly appeared from plot #13 - an empty grave.','foff?ope=2&cid=4138');
```

and it throws this in my face:

*1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''A zombie that suddenly appeared from plot' at line 12*

so I thought "oh well, I'll fix that in a few seconds" - but nothing stood out. so I went checked the error message and thought "well, that can't be it, can it?" but sure enough, the # sign caused an error. That's...weird I thought.

Anyway, I get distracted and then come back to the computer and try to pick up where I left off, so I copied the data I inserted but this time I left out the top row, (the skull Servant) and forgot to remove the # sign...and that code worked!

**Question is...HOW how can removing the # sign in a piece of text make the code work - OR keeping that # sign and removing the top row?**

I've gone through it over and over again and the data I'm inputting doesn't look weird or have anything that sticks out, so how is this even possible?

I'm starting to think ghosts are responsible for this weird behaviour. Please explain this bizzare behaviour to me, 'cause I really don't know how that could fix it.

Comment: MyISAM? What century is this?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b2df8c6bf7189c488d566b7506798aa), at least not in the demo.  I used a CTE, but that shouldn't matter if your literal data had some problem.

Comment: `#` in fact is one way to leave a comment in your MySQL code.  But, if enclosed in a string literal, it should be recognized as a literal `#`, _without_ the need to escape it.

Comment: yeah, that's what I figgured too, but if it isn't recognized as a literal # that would explain why it's giving me a headache I guess

Comment: and just to make sure, I did try to escape it, but as you would expect, it didn't work.

Comment: the char #  inside quote work for me .. how you are trying to insert  ... by a server side language ,, by console ??

Comment: right now I'm being lazy so I'm using phpMyAdmin - but I found the issue when doing a mysqli query with php

Comment: right, I've googled around a bit and it seems people are saying it's a bug in my version of mysql. Guess I need to update to a newer version this year too :-P

Comment: Here's a bit of fun fact - even though both single qoutes and double quotes are string literals in mysql, aparantly escaping only works within double qoute string literals by default settings.

That's just silly if you ask me.